# Conditional type based on a mapped type

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a type safe variant of a client/server communication, where I used mapped types to define parameters required to send a request and the return values in a response for that request. Here's an example of each type:

```js
export interface IProtocolParameters {
    "authenticate": { username: string; password: string };
    "getLogLevel": {};
}
```

and

```js
export interface IProtocolFinalResult {
    "authenticate": { activeProfile: ICommShellProfile };
    "getLogLevel": { result: string };
```

Unfortunately there are APIs which return multiple responses, so I have to collect them in an array. That's why I defined my actual response type and the promise returning it as:

```js
export type ResponseType<K extends keyof IProtocolFinalResult> =
    Array<IProtocolFinalResult[K]> | IProtocolFinalResult[K];

export type ResponsePromise<K extends keyof IProtocolFinalResult> = Promise<ResponseType<K>>;
```

This has the drawback that everywhere I consume such a result I have first to test if it is an array:

```js
    public async getLogLevel(): Promise<string> {
        const response = await MessageScheduler.get.sendSimpleRequest({
            requestType: "getLogLevel",
            parameters: {},
        });

        return Array.isArray(response) ? response[0].result : response.result;
    }
```

which is inconvenient (especially given that I have hundreds of APIs). I'm now looking for a way to improve that by using a conditional type that either returns an array of `IProtocolFinalResult[K]` or just `IProtocolFinalResult[K]`, depending on the API.

From the documentation I understand that you can use a conditional type only based on inheritance, not based on another condition (a flag or a mapped type etc.). Any other idea what I could do here?

What I have in mind is something like:

```js
export type ResponseType<K extends keyof IProtocolFinalResult> = multiResults.has(K) ? Array<IProtocolFinalResult[K]> : IProtocolFinalResult[K];
```

with

```js
const multiResults: Set<string> = new Set(["listSomething"]);
```

Here's a [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#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-bwAOjdfIPS9H0M28GNl2PPlMUFSQuF4fhBBEMQB2PcUcSlGhJDoNVD0AsBzRATshH0DEJ1aKcK2Qc8ex9QCCH4GNyIISjwSYQ9mCAA) for this code..

Comment: In your API client, have you tried adding a **response interceptor** which can do the heavy lifting? For instance, if you get a single object in response, convert it to array. That way, you will always get array in your response handlers. Or, if you want to just take the first entry from the array always, then you can do that as well in the interceptor.

Comment: Yes, I have that in place already, but wondered if I can avoid having to put it always in an array. I guess, if I get no answer here I have to go this route, however.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code sample that demonstrates the issue? Preferably in the typescript playground? What you want sounds doable but I'd have to se a more concrete example of what you are doing

Comment: Why dont you encode the type of the response in `IProtocolFinalResult` for example: `"listSomthing": RESULT_ELEM[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that you can use a conditional type only based on inheritance, not based on another condition (a flag or a mapped type etc.)

Typescript's string typing allows you to have both. If you have a `type Foo = "a" | "b" | "c"`, then inheritance is equivalent to a "contains" kind of check (because the type `"a"` is a subtype of `"a" | "b" | "c"`).

```
type multiResults = "authenticate" | "getLogLevels";

export type ResponseType<K extends keyof IProtocolFinalResult> =
  K extends multiResults
    ? Array<IProtocolFinalResult[K]>
    : IProtocolFinalResult[K];
```

If you also want the information at runtime, not just at compile time, and still have a single source of truth, that's also possible:

```
const multiResults = ["authenticate", "getLogLevels"] as const;

export type ResponseType<K extends keyof IProtocolFinalResult> =
  K extends typeof multiResults[number]
    ? Array<IProtocolFinalResult[K]>
    : IProtocolFinalResult[K];
```

Comment: This answer is just awesome! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is define which response is `Array` in the `IProtocolFinalResult`.

For example, `authenticate` returns array:

```js
export interface IProtocolFinalResult {
    "authenticate": Array<{ activeProfile: ICommShellProfile }>;
    "getLogLevel": { result: string };
}
```

and then, `ResponseType` will be:

```js
export type ResponseType<K extends keyof IProtocolFinalResult> = IProtocolFinalResult[K];
```

after this, when you try to access the response of `getLogLevel`, it will not be consider as a array anymore.

an extra case:

if `authenticate` **may** returns an array, the `IProtocolFinalResult` can be:

```js
type MaybeArray<T> = T | Array<T>

export interface IProtocolFinalResult {
    "authenticate": MaybeArray<{ activeProfile: ICommShellProfile }>;
    "getLogLevel": { result: string };
}
```

Comment: That was actually my first thought too! I could encode that in the response mapping. But it doesn't work this way, because it would change the definition of a single response (that mapper contains the information how a single response looks like).

Comment: You may need another interface to define all data modal (_single response_). the data model and the response type should be separate.

Comment: Right, this is what the accepted answer uses (and what I originally had in mind).